# Random 6 Digit Number (no duplication) MS Access 2010 database?

Tags: vba, ms-access, random

I have a database that has a form that generates an ID for a particular set of information in MS Access Database. This ID is meant to be the current date and a random 6 digit number. Currently I have the date field with a default of `=Date()` and the random number field with a default of this `Right(Format(Rnd()*1000000,'000000'),6)` to get the 6 digits, then I use this `=[DateRequested] & "-" & [RandomNumber]` in the ID field to get a concatenated version of the fields with a dash in the center. Both are working correctly, but when I close and reopen the database I am getting the same progression of numbers. I have seen a little on here about issuing a `Randomize` statement in the code, but I am not very good at code and do not know how to implement this.

I tried doing this this from what I could put together from threads:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Randomize()
End Sub
```

but I get this error message:

> Compile error: Expected: =

I just need to know what I need to change in order to get the database to pull a new 6 digit number every time the database is opened, rather then the same set of numbers every time.

Comment: why not just timestamp it? Is the user base so large that there might be a concern about clicking exactly at the sametime? if not then `=[DateRequested] & "-" & Format(Date,"ddmmyyyyHhNnSs")` seems like it would work fine and be more descriptive. Or if DateRequested = Date Then just use `=Format(Date,"mm/dd/yyyy-HhNnSs")` the reason i suggest this even though you are asking for 6 digits is that your random number may duplicate by happenstance this will not unless the computer time is off or 2 users invoke at the exact same second.

Comment: The ID is being used to de-identify data and will be used for associating information with each other. The user base is small, so clicking at the same time is not really an issue. However, I do need the number to be 6 digits. I did try your code anyhow though and it is generating "12/16/2013-Date".

Comment: Sorry should be `Format(Date(),"ddmmyyyyHhNnSs")`

Comment: Hmm that makes some sense. Temporarily I have set it to =[DateRequested] & "-" & Format(Now(),"HhNnSs") because this keeps the 6 digit format and doesn't reduplicate date. The Now() function returned the other fields, when I had just Date() it was all coming up 00. But I hadn't thought of doing this prior. My only concern is that if someone were to enter data at the same time it might not be unique.

Comment: Yes but this would have to occur at the exact same second and Randomize will have the same issue of a possible duplication at least this way the occurrence has meaning. Sorry you are correct I forgot that Date() sets time to 00:00:00 Now() is correct.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to mix it up as "SsHhNn" just to make it less obvious as to what the number is, but that was a creative solution to a problem that has been causing me many issues!

Comment: glad I can help also know you can call each parameter as many times as you'd like so something like `Mid(Format(Now(), "HSsHhNnSsHhNnSsSsNnHh"), 16 * Rnd + 1, 6)` would be similarly Random since the formatting is 22 digits long this will take the middle 6 starting at a random number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove parenthesis from call to Randomize

Comment: I have tried that as well, but all that causes is me to get the same set of numbers again. Is it the location where I am placing the code possibly?

Comment: @mw90: you should call Randomize before starting to generate random numbers. OR you can define a function that calls Randomize and returns Rnd(), and call this function instead of directly call Rnd(). First option performs better, maybe an autoexec macro? If not, second option should work.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to do either of the things you are mentioning. But, I think you are saying I need to put the Rnd() code after the Randomize code in VB?

Comment: @mw90: For first option, see [Autoexec macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-HA010336239.aspx=). From this macro call `Randomize`.  For second option, define a function `Function myRnd() as Single` that simply does `Randomize : myRnd = Rnd()`. In your code call myRnd() instead of Rnd().